# getting the correct regex to print out in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Below is a regex statement I have been working on for quite sometime:

```
Match parsedRequestData = Regex.Match(requestData, @"^.*\[(.*)\]$");
```

What this is supposed to be doing is taking the email out of the email below:

```
2.3|[0246303@up.com]
```

For clarification, this email comes from a table in SQL Server. There are many emails that are formatted like this in there and the regex is supposed to be getting all of that from inside the brackets. However, it is matching the entirety of this line instead of whats inside of it. So my question is, is there something wrong with my regex statement or do I have something in my code I need to add?

Comment: Or for a single know match `x = x.Remove(x.Length - 1).Substring(1 + x.IndexOf('['));`

Comment: You have kept this question open by not marking an answer...is there something you are running into?

Answer (score 1):

Your `regex` is storing the email address in capture group 1.  Try referencing group 1 like this:

```
parsedRequestData.Groups[1];
```

Code Sample:

```
string requestData = "2.3|[0246303@up.com]";
Match parsedRequestData = Regex.Match(requestData, @"^.*\[(.*)\]$");
if (parsedRequestData.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(parsedRequestData.Groups[1]);
}
```

Results:

```
0246303@up.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is OK. All you need is to use the `Group[1]`

```
var email = Regex.Match("2.3|[0246303@up.com]", @"^.*\[(.*)\]$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, it is matching the entirety of this line instead of whats inside of it.

Unless one uses named match captures, the match capture groups are indexed.

- Match.Groups[0].Value is the whole match; it shows all the match captures and all the grouped matched text.
- Match.Groups[{1-N}].Value is the match **captures** in the order of specification in the pattern for anything in a `( )` parenthesis set(s). If there is only one `( )` there will be two indexed groups; 0 as mentioned above, and 1 of the items specified to be captured to N.

You only have one `( )` set so the data you want is found in **match capture group 1**. Group 0 has the non match capture items along with the match capture data.

If one names the match capture such as `(?<MyNameHere> )` one can also access the match via `Match.Groups["MyNameHere"].Value`.

---

**Suggestion on your pattern away from the answer**

Usage of `*` (*zero* or more) in patterns can be problematic in that it can significantly increase the time of the parser takes due to *backtracking* false scenarios.

If one knows there is text to be found, don't tell the parser **zero** items may happen when that is impossible, change it to `+` one or more. That slight change can greatly affect the parsing operations, both in time and operations.

Change `^.*\[(.*)\]$` to `^.+\[(.+)\]$`.

But to even increase the efficiency of the pattern, focus on the knowns of the characters `[` and `]` as anchors.

**Pattern Restructure To Use Anchors**

```
^[^[]+\[([^\]]+)[\s\]]+$
```

Why is this pattern better? Because we will look for "[" and "]" as anchors.

Let us break it down

- `^` - Beginning of the pattern (a hard anchor)
- `[^ ]+` This is a set notation where the `^` says NOT.
- `[^\[]+` So we want to capture all text `+` (one or more) that is NOT a `[`. This tells the pattern to match up to our anchor `[` in the text. Note that we don't have to escape it for regex parser treats all characters in a set `[ ]` as a literal so `[^[]` is valid. (To be clear this is a *match but don't capture* text anchor so we will not find this text in an index above the 0 index; only in 0).
- `\[` Our literal anchor the "[" character.
- `([^\]]+)` This is our match capture which says match this set where any character is valid but not an "]". Here we have to escape the ] because otherwise it would signify the end of our set.
- `[\s\]]+` we know the end of our text there will be spaces and the "]" character, so let us match (but not to capture) any combination of spaces and a ] before the end.
- `$` our final anchor, the end of the file/buffer indicator (or line if the right parser rule is set).